# Getting an error when attempting to install a cocoapod from a mercurial repo by commit

Tags: ios, mercurial, cocoapods

I currently have a cocoapod in a mercurial repo that I can install with the following line in my podfile without errors:

```
pod 'MyPod', :hg => 'https://hg.example.com/pod/mypod'
```

However, I want to specify a certain commit for my Podfile to target, based on information [seen here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html).

Specifically,

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :commit => '0f506b1c45'
```

However, that example is for a git repo, not a mercurial repo.

When I add the commit repo, as seen below, I get the following error message:

```
pod 'MyPod', :hg => 'https://hg.example.com/pod/mypod', :commit => 'abcd1234'
```

> Analyzing dependencies Pre-downloading: `MyPod` from
>   `https://hg.example.com/pod/mypod`, commit `abcd1234`
>
> [!] Error installing MyPod Unrecognized options `[:commit]`

While I know I can also tag the commit and point my podfile to that, doing so it not an option in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change commit to revision. I could not locate this anywhere on their example page.

```
pod 'MyPod', :hg => 'https://hg.example.com/pod/mypod', :revision => 'abcd1234'
```